# When try to convert django dict to json object it says "'str' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Tags: python, ajax, json, django

I need to update HTML table when dropdown vale change.I'm using Ajax to do this.
Here is the HTML code and Ajax code
HTML code

```
<form role="form" action="/surveys/viewsurveys/{{ survey_id }}"   method="post" >
  <div class="form-group">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="Surey_ID" name="Surey_ID" value="{{ survey_id }}">
    <label>Select Department or Section</label>
    <select id="dept" name="dept" class="form-control" onchange="allusers();">
      {% for items in dept_data  %}
         <option value="{{ items.id }}">{{ items.dept_name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
 <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">All &nbsp<small class="badge pull-right bg-green"> {{ counts.hr_count }}</small></h3>
 </div><!-- /.box-header -->

  <div class="box-body table-responsive">
  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th> </th>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Username</th>
           <th>Data join</th>
           <th>last login</th>
           <th>Is Active</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {% for items in allusers %}
              <tr >
                <td>
                   <div class="input-group">
                       <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <input name="{{ items.id }}" type="checkbox">
                       </span>
                   </div><!-- /input-group -->
                 </td>
                 <td>{{ items.first_name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.last_name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.email }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.username }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.date_join }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.last_login }}</td>
                 <td>{{ items.is_active }}</td>
                 <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="/accounts/editusers/{{ items.id }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>
               </td>
              </tr>
           {% endfor %}   
       </tbody>
           <tfoot>
             <tr>
                <th> </th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Data join</th>
                <th>last login</th>
                <th>Is Active</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
     </table>
 </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</form>
```

Ajax code

```
function allusers()
  {

    $.ajax({
          url : "/surveys/ajaxalldeptusers",
          type : "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data : {
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
             dept: $('#dept').val(),
             Surey_ID:$('#Surey_ID').val(),


          },

          success : function(json) {
           //$('#result').append( 'Server Response: ' + json.server_response);
           $('#box').html(json.message),
           console.log('my message' + json)
          },
          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
          alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
          }

        });

  }
```

back-end

```
def ajax_all_dept_users(request):
    try:
        request.session['user_login_data']
        dept_data=SuUserDepartment.objects.filter(org=request.session['user_login_data']['org'])
        dept=request.POST.get('dept','')
        survey_id=request.POST.get('Surey_ID','')
        responce_data={}

        if request.method == 'POST':
            surey_data=SuSurey.objects.get(id=survey_id)
            allusers=SuUser.objects.filter(dept_id=dept)
            responce_data['allusers']=allusers
            responce_data['dept_data']=dept_data
            responce_data['surey_data']=surey_data
            responce_data['survey_id']=survey_id
            data = serializers.serialize('json', responce_data)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
            #return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'allusers':allusers,'dept_data':dept_data,'surey_data':surey_data, 'survey_id':survey_id }),content_type="application/json")
            #return  render_to_response("pages/forms/publish.html",{'allusers':allusers,'dept_data':dept_data,'surey_data':surey_data, 'survey_id':survey_id },context_instance=RequestContext(request))


    except KeyError, e:
        messages={'alert':'You need to loging'}
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'messages': messages},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I try to debug and try to figure out the problem.I found that when come to  serializers.serialize() it give this error

[image]

how can i fix this error? need a quick help

Answer (score 1):

That is a common error with serializers.serialize

You're trying to serialize an object that is not a model queryset.

Your data object is a dictionary, so you don't need to serialize it, just return that dict with json dump.

Comment: I tried that also and i got [<SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>, <SuUserDepartment: SuUserDepartment object>] is not JSON serializable

Comment: I dont know what are you doing. But return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'responce_data': responce_data}),
                                content_type='application/json; charset=utf8') must work. And response_data must be a dictionary {key: value}. As I say, serializers.serialize is for queryset objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
responce_data['allusers']=allusers
responce_data['dept_data']=dept_data
responce_data['surey_data']=surey_data
responce_data['survey_id']=survey_id
data = serializers.serialize('json', responce_data)
```

Here your call passing dict `response_data` to serializer, rather you should pass list of objects that you want to serialize.

So create list of objects and also do not specify string `survey_id` in the list to serialize.

Update your code to

```
dept_data=list(SuUserDepartment.objects.filter(org=request.session['user_login_data']['org']))

allusers=list(SuUser.objects.filter(dept_id=dept))
responce_data = [ surey_data, ] + dept_data + allusers
data = serializers.serialize('json', responce_data)
```

Comment: i try and got this error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: @user3480706, you need to create list from the queryset. See the updated answer to create list.

Comment: it says 'SuSurey' object is not iterable

Comment: @user3480706, you may want to show the updated code.